# Physics journals that focus on expository work

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

As the title says, I'm looking for journals that focus on expository work in Physics. What I mean is that the journal is less focused on communication between professionals and more on disseminating knowledge to the wider physics community, including students. For example *Physical Review Letters* are a great series of journals, but their terse length limits combined with their prestige means that most of the articles are meant for a narrow group of professionals studying a very specific topic. It would be nice to read a peer-reviewed journal that you are able to really dive into and come out with a new comprehension of topics you might not have fully understood before. I've found that the *American Journal of Physics* is pretty good in this regard. I'm wondering if there are any others.

Comment: Maybe Physics Today?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [Reviews of Modern Physics](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/about) has been created exactly with that scope, as you can see in the link. Feynman's article on the path integral approach, for example, was published on this journal.
- [Physics Reports](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/physics-reports/) is similar to Rev. Mod. Phys. albeit the article submission is by invitation only.
- [Reports on Progress in Physics](http://iopscience.iop.org/0034-4885/page/Scope) is another one.

Answer (score 1):

The American Association Institute of Physics (AIP; the parent organization of the APS and AAPT among others) publishes *[The Physics Teacher](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/tpt)*, which publishes articles on pedagogy and exposition.

Their blurb reads:

> Dedicated to the strengthening of the teaching of introductory physics at all levels, The Physics Teacher provides peer-reviewed materials to be used in the classrooms and instructional laboratories. It includes:
>
> Innovative physics demonstrations; New ways of doing lab experiments; Ideas for presenting difficult concepts more clearly; Suggestions for implementing newer technology into teaching; Historical insights that can enrich the physics course and Book and film reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but physics news websites, like phys.org and nature news are really good for "exposition" of different topics. I'm a PhD student in physics and I use phys.org and nature news and views (http://www.nature.com/subjects/physics#news-and-views) to have a non-technical source for other physical subjects and if I'm interested in a more technical and in depth treatment I'll check out the peer reviewed papers associated with those articles.